# Jquery add totalprice of 1 element only and show finalprice but not add other elements

Tags: jquery, html

The code and jquery for the code is given it add only one element but remaining are not added please see the following code

```
[![the output table not add the total price][1]][1]
```

```js
 <script>
                        jQuery('.plus').click(function() {
                            var qut = jQuery(this).prev().val();

                            var plus = (parseInt(qut) + 1);
                            jQuery(this).prev().val(plus);
                            if (plus > parseInt(0)) {
                                var price = jQuery(this).prev().data('price');
                                jQuery(this).parent().next().html(parseInt(plus) * parseInt(price));
                            } else {

                                jQuery(this).parent().next().html(price);
                            }
                            var price = [];
                            var p = 0;
                            jQuery('.finalprice').each(function() {
                                p = (parseInt(p) + parseInt(jQuery(this).html()));
                            });
                            jQuery('.totalprice').html(p);

                        });

                        jQuery('.minus').click(function() {
                            var qut = jQuery(this).next().val();

                            var plus = (parseInt(qut) - 1);
                            if (plus > parseInt(0)) {
                                jQuery(this).next().val(plus);

                                var price = jQuery(this).next().data('price');
                                jQuery(this).parent().next().html(parseInt(plus) * parseInt(price));
                            } else {

                                jQuery(this).parent().next().html(price);
                            }
 var p = 0;
                            jQuery('.finalprice').each(function() {
                                p = (parseInt(p) + parseInt(jQuery(this).html()));
                            });
                            jQuery('.totalprice').html(p);

                        });
</script>
```

```html
 <form method="post" action="confirm.php" class="">
                <div class="col span_2_of_3">
                    <table class="shippingtable" width="100%">
                        <tbody><tr class="heading"> <td colspan="3"><div align="center">Order Details</div></td></tr>
        <tr class="titles"><td width="450px">Menu Name</td><td width="100px">Quantity</td>
        <td>Price</td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td>Lemon Tea</td><td><span class="minus" style="font-size:17px!important;">-</span><input readonly class="Quantity" style="text-align:center" size="3" type="text" name="quantity" data-price="45"
         value="1"><span class="plus"style="font-size:17px!important;">+</span> </td><td calss="finalprice">45</td></tr><tr><td>Ice Tea</td><td><span class="minus" style="font-size:17px!important;">-</span><input readonly class="Quantity" style="text-align:center" size="3" type="text" name="quantity" data-price="50"
         value="1"><span class="plus"style="font-size:17px!important;">+</span> </td><td calss="finalprice">50</td></tr>       <tr>
       <td>VANILA MILKSHAKE</td>
       <td>
       <span class="minus" style="font-size:17px!important;">-</span> 
       <input readonly class="Quantity" style="text-align:center" size="3" 
       type="text" name="quantity" data-price="70" value="1"> 
       <span class="plus" style="font-size:17px!important;">+</span>
       </td>
       <td class="finalprice">70</td>
       </tr> 
       
           <tr><td></td><td><div align="right">Total Price : </div></td><td class="totalprice" style="font-weight: bold;"></td></tr>
                    </tbody></table>
```

the above code will not show addition of all contents in result the Vanila milkshake is static and other are call from another page it add only vanila value not other in **.totalprice**

Comment: There is typo in your HTML. You have kept `calss="finalprice"` instead of `class="finalprice"`

Comment: Here is **[the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/83rx6w9q/)** with class name corrected as pointed out by @Chitrang

Comment: Thank you sir its my big mistake!!